# Print value from Views field & HTML into Colorbox Image caption?

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I have created a view for an image gallery with the images using the colorbox field formatter so that they open up in a colorbox window when clicked.

I would also like to display the values from the other fields in the relevant field collection in each colorbox's caption but the built in custom caption option in views does not support html markup and is only limited to around 100 characters regardless.

What would be the best way to print values from my view and html inside the colorbox's caption / `#cboxTitle` div ? I have tried messing about with the `colorbox_image_formatter` and `colorbox_imagefield` functions but to no avail.

[image: colorbox]